# We have 'index' and 'rindex', we have 'find' but no 'rfind'

Tags: ruby

When applied to an Array, `index` (invoked with a block) returns the index of the first element satisfying the condition, and `rindex` returns the index of the last one. Similarly, we have `find` to return the element itself. However, there is no corresponding `rfind` that would return the last element of an array satisfying a condition.

Does Ruby already have a method that accomplishes this?

Before monkey-patching the `Array` class, I want to make sure.

Comment: We probably have `rindex` in Ruby, because Perl has `rindex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
enum = [1, 2, 3, 4].reverse_each
# => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3, 4]:reverse_each>

enum.find(&:odd?)
# => 3
```

Notice that, unlike using `Array#reverse`, it does not create a temporal array that is thrown out immediately.

Doing it at once:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reverse_each.find(&:odd?)
# => 3
```

In other words, we have `reverse_each.find` instead of `rfind`; not a big deal.

Comment: @GaganGami It's written in my answer.